# How to take the value after every 10 min?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, feature-engineering

I am using LSTM for forecasting the stock prediction , I did some feature engineering on time series data .I have two columns , first is price and second is date . Now I want to train the model which take the value of price after every ten minutes . Suppose :

```
date_index    date      new_price
        
08:28:31    08:28:31    8222000.0
08:28:35    08:28:35    8222000.0
08:28:44    08:28:44    8200000.0
08:28:50    08:28:50    8210000.0
08:28:56    08:28:56    8060000.0
08:29:00    08:29:00    8110000.0
08:29:00    08:29:00    8110000.0
08:29:05    08:29:05    8010000.0
08:29:24    08:29:24    8222000.0
08:29:28    08:29:28    8210000.0
```

Lets say the date comes first is **8:28:31** it will takes the value of its corresponding price and at the second time it should take the value of corresponding columns after ten minutes means **8:38:31** , and sometimes this time does not available in data . How to do it . My goal is just to train the model on after every 10 minutes or 15 minutes ?

Comment: So what value do you take if 8:38:31 doesn't exist? Do you want `NaN` or the next value after that?

Comment: I want to take the next value after that not Nan , but if it exists after 10 minutes then it is fine , if  not take some very next value

Comment: Be careful with taking the very next value; if you take the next value but pretend it was at the "originally" desired timestamp, you might introduce **look-ahead bias** into your model.

Answer (score 0):

The main keyword you are looking for here is **resampling**

You have time-series data with unevenly spaced time stamps and want to convert the index to something more regular (i.e. 10 minute intervals).

The question you have to answer is: If the exact 10 minute timestamp is *not* available in your data, what *do* you want to do? Take the most recent event instead?

(Let's say the data for **8:38:31** is not available, but there's data for **8::37:25**. Do you just want to take *that*?)

If so, I think something like `df.resample(_some_argument_to_set_interval_to_10_minutes).last()` should work, where I forgot the exact syntax for setting the interval in the `resample` method. Might be something like `10m` or something.

See here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#resampling

Comment: Please write the exact line of  code , I want to include in the code

Comment: You didn't give any code for context either, so I can't tell you exactly what you should do.